# Small tablet as control device for home automatization

Tags: tablet

I want to control several things like lighting via Ethernet using self developed android apps. For this reason I need a solid base hardware with the following features:

Must have

- **Rocksolid hardware which doesn't fail after warranty expiration (Like it is the case with the Google Nexus 7)**
- Android OS
- Alternative stable Lolipop-based ROM available
- Rootable
- At least 7" display but not more than 8"
- Available in Europe
- Price not above 200€

Nice to have

- Proximity sensor
- Light sensor
- Wireless charging
- Camera
- Microphone

Since the device will be only used as a remote control, performance doesn't matter that much.